# sqlsrv_connect() not found

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working on a project that uses the SQL Server Driver for PHP, and want to upgrade the driver to the new version (2.0), because I need some of the functions that have been implemented there.

I replaced the old .dll in the php/ext directory and restarted the web server. But now I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in E:\ProjekteExtern\hades\_apl\classes\sql\sqlsrv.class.php on line 34
```

The `phpinfo()` output shows sqlsrv, just like with the previous version.

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error or have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: you could try to use PDO, they write that version 2.0 supports that. (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296203%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems like the PDO version is missing some functions, like sqlsrv_num_rows()... i will try it later, but getting the normal driver to run would be much nicer i think :)

Answer (score 1):

For those still having errors with PHP and Microsoft SQL Server using PHP SQL, check the web server's log (Apache, IIS, etc). I have just found out that [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) x64 [is not compatible with PHP SQL Server Driver](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,74646), so I'm installing the 32-bit version back again.

**UPDATE**:
for WampServer 2.2, PHP is compiled thread-safe and with VC++ 9.0, so it works using either

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

or

```
php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

Comment: Updating my answer because of changes in WampServer 2.2. Actually the PHP SQL Server dll should be thread-safe and compiled with VC++9.